# How can I set x_ticks for a heatmap in Seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to change the x_ticks from  `[0.01, 0.02, ......1.01]`
to `[0.1,0.2,...,1.0]`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

colums = np.arange(0.01, 1.01, 0.01)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 100)), columns=colums.tolist())
ax1 = sns.heatmap(df, vmin=0., vmax=1, linewidths=.05, cbar_kws={'label': '?'})
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to adjust the ticks via `ax1.set_xticks([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])` but it did not work.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, the tick positions are *categorical*: `0, 1, 2, ...`. So you can call `ax1.set_ticks([9, 19, 29, ...])` to have ticks for the columns named `0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ...`. And then call `ax1.set_ticklabels(...)` to set the desired strings:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 100)))
ax1 = sns.heatmap(df, vmin=0., vmax=1, linewidths=.05, cbar_kws={'label': '?'})
# ax1.set_xticks(range(4, 100, 5))
# ax1.set_xticklabels(f'{c:.2f}' for c in np.arange(0.05, 1.01, 0.05))
ax1.set_xticks(range(9, 100, 10))
ax1.set_xticklabels(f'{c:.1f}' for c in np.arange(0.1, 1.01, 0.1))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: If you want the columns to have nice names (default they are just `0,1,2,...`), you can create the dataframe as `pd.DataFrame(..., columns=[f'{c:.2f}' for c in np.arange(0.01, 1.01, 0.01)])`. That way the column names will be strings with the desired precision. If you just use numbers instead of strings, pandas converts these to strings (via `str()`) without knowing how many digits are needed. Unavoidable rounding errors can create undesired strings such as `0.21000000000000002`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little bit ugly but it works for me.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

colums = np.arange(0.01, 1.01, 0.01)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 100)), columns=colums.tolist())

def round(n, k):
    # function to round number 'n' up/down to nearest 'k'
    # use positive k to round up
    # use negative k to round down

    return n - n % k

# note: the df.index is a series of elevation values
tick_step = 25 
tick_min = int(round(df.index.min(), (-1 * tick_step)))  # round down
tick_max = (int(round(df.index.max(), (1 * tick_step)))) + tick_step  # round up

# the depth values for the tick labels 
# I want my y tick labels to refer to these elevations, 
# but with min and max values being a multiple of 25.
xticklabels = range(tick_min, tick_max, tick_step)
# the index position of the tick labels
xticks = []
for label in xticklabels:
    idx_pos = df.index.get_loc(label)
    xticks.append(idx_pos)

cmap = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", 128)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
ax1 = sns.heatmap(df, annot=False, cmap=cmap, xticklabels=xticklabels)
ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
plt.show()
```

[image]